# How to make a duration picker react native

Tags: react-native, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am trying to build a duration picker:
it would look like a simple ios time picker, but it would start with 0 minutes and 0 seconds and go up to 23 hours and 59 minutes.
I tried using normal DateTimePickers ([react native date picker](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker)), and using the 24 hours format, and that would work. The problem is that ios doesn't support the 24 hours format.

PS: the 12 hours format, as you can see  from the image, starts from 1 hour and 0 minutes, so that would not be good if someone would want to take 20 minutes, for example.

It would look something like this, but in 24 hours format, starting from 0 hours and 0 minutes, and going till 23 and 59 minutes.

[image: Date picker example]

Comment: this is not a duration picker, rather a time picker right?

Comment: Yes but my goal is pick a duration (from 0 minutes to 23 hours and 59 minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to implement this:
I used another library ([react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker)) and, as said in the [docs](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker), you can't set a 24 hours format on ios, but what you can do is setting

```
locale="en_GB"
```

Using this you can now achieve this look:

[image: date time picker]

As you can see you will be able to choose even times with 0 hours.

To get the minutes, on the Date object you will get as a prop of `onConfirm`, do this:

```
const minutes = date.getMinutes() + date.getHours() * 60;
console.log(minutes);
```

Finally, if you want your DurationPicker to start at 0 0, set the prop `date` to a date with 0 hours and 0 minutes.

At the end it is going to look something like this:

```
<DateTimePicker
  mode='time'
  date={new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))}
  locale='en_GB'
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't show the seconds though. This library seems to work on React but not react native: https://github.com/flurmbo/react-duration-picker

Comment: yes this doesn't show the seconds, but it's because it's not built for it. I just adapted it to make a duration picker. Proabably there is a way to create a custom one with native ios, but I don't know it yet (if anyone knows it would be way better)